# Is there a way to measure allergy to tablet/pill ingredients?

Tags: allergy, test, pill

It looks like I have some kind of allergy to tablets/pills. It doesn't matter which type I take (I used to take mainly vitamins).

If I take some, the result is vary from bearable sickness (for 2 days) to immediate anaphylaxia (happened twice altogether).

I went to an allergist, but **I was told that it is difficult to measure which component of the tablet/pill I am allergic to bcs most of the components are secret.**

(*I have the assumption that it must be some basic ingredients, since it does not matter which brand or type of tablet I am taking. There were some exceptions when I didn't get ill, but the reaction happens in 80% of the cases. 
The syndromes are present since  childhood, just during the time they became more strong and frequent.*)

I was told by the doctor to simply not take any tablets. But I would like to know which ingredient(s) I am allergic to. Maybe it is present in other products I may take accidently.  I don't even know if this type of allergy is a well-known one...

**My question: is there a method to indicate which component of basic tablet/pill ingredients can cause allergic reactions?**

Comment: Inactive ingredients or [excipients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excipient) include binders, coatings, sweeteners, etc. On Dailymed.nlm.nih.gov you can check for inactive ingredients in many pills. Allergologists should have detailed lists of those that commonly trigger allergic reactions. You can search for "allergy to excipients" or "drug additives" to learn more. Also, you can make a collection of actual tablets/pills you reacted to them and show them to an allergologist, who can then make tests and find the problematic substance. Not sure if anyone other can do this better.

Comment: @Jan It's best to avoid answering in comments.

Comment: @BryanKrause, I did not provide an answer but suggested the OP to search for specific terms and to encourage a visit to an allergologist. So, basically the OP can search and get the answer; otherwise it's just me or someone other doing it instead of him.

Comment: See an allergist and if you don't get help there, see someone else. Medications do not have "secret" components, all ingredients must by law be described.  You need to get this figured out sooner than later; your life may one day depend on taking a medication and you will need to know what you are and aren't allergic to.